# How to display something on Thymeleaf table if not null

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a table:

```
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Header1</th>
    <th>Header2</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <div th:if="${param1 != null}">
    <td class="dripicons-checkmark"></td>
  </div>
  <div th:if="${param2 != null}">
    <td class="dripicons-checkmark"></td>
  </div>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

param1 and param2 are coming from my controller:

```
model.addAttribute("param1", param1)
model.addAttribute("param2", param2)
```

...and they can be `null` or contain some info. I'm trying to show a checkmark under correct header. If `param1` is not `null`, I want to show the checkmark under `Header1` and if `param2` is not `null`, I want to show the checkmark under `Header2` and so on. The code above shows the checkmark always under `Header1`, if either one of the params are not null. How can I put the icon under a correct header?

Comment: You are only checking param1, then it will show under  header 1 only.

Comment: @SangamBelose That was a typo, thank you for pointing out. I am checking both params in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If either one of your params is `null`, then you will only be creating one `<td>` cell in the `<tr>` row. Your table always needs two cells to match the two headings you have.

There are various ways around this. The following is one way, which I think is reasonably concise:

```
<tbody>
    <td th:class="${param1} != null ? 'dripicons-checkmark' : null"></td>
    <td th:class="${param2} != null ? 'dripicons-checkmark' : null"></td>
</tbody>
```

In this example, we always have two row cells.

The "if" condition is inside a `th:class` attribute, so there is no need for any surrounding `<div>` elements.

The HTML generated by this is as follows, when the first value is null, but the second value is not null:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header1</th>
            <th>Header2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="dripicons-checkmark"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```